# how to extract data from a code using python

Tags: python, text-extraction

I have some functions, as .txt files which are written using easy language and I need to extract data from those functions using python. as an example consider the following part.

code segment -

```
If MarketPosition = 0 and (EntriesToday(Date) < 1 or EndofSess) and
EntCondL 
then begin
    Buy("EnStop-L") NShares shares next bar at EntPrL stop;
end;
```

in here, I need to extract the parts

- **MarketPosition = 0**
- **EntriesToday(Date) < 1**
- **EndofSess**
- **EntCondL**

and identify `=`, `<` signs using python.
thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably need a language parser or [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)

Comment: Is it always between `If...then` or is that just an example?

Comment: @Venify it's always between If...then, and end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for finding and splitting the text between `if` and `then`
The result is a list of the individual elements: variables, brackets and the comparison operators.

```
code = """
If MarketPosition = 0 and (EntriesToday(Date) < 1 or EndofSess) and
EntCondL 
then begin
    Buy("EnStop-L") NShares shares next bar at EntPrL stop;
end;
"""

import re
words = re.split("\s+|(\(|\)|<|>|=|;)", code)

is_if = False
results = []
current = None
for token in words:
    if not token:
        continue
    elif token.lower() == "if":
        is_if = True
        current = []
    elif token.lower() == "then":
        is_if = False
        results.append(current)
    elif is_if:
        if token.isdecimal(): # Detect numbers
            try:
                current.append(int(token))
            except ValueError:
                current.append(float(token))
        else: # otherwise just take the string
            current.append(token)



print(results)
```

The result:

```
['MarketPosition', '=', 0, 'and', '(', 'EntriesToday', '(', 'Date', ')', '<', 1, 'or', 'EndofSess', ')', 'and', 'EntCondL']
```

I think it's easier to go from here 
(I don't in which form you need the data, for example do the brackets matter?)

Comment: as you said brackets doesn't matter actually ... i was able to get the job done through your code fragment. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for prefix and postfix of some operators 
i suggest you to find these list of operators and use it's location to get prefix and postfix